# Maven - exception during project building

Tags: java, maven

When I'm trying to build project I get exception:

> Downloading:
>   http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.14/log4j-1.2.14.jar
>   Nov 4, 2012 5:47:16 PM
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector
>   tryExecute INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when
>   processing request: Connection reset Nov 4, 2012 5:47:16 PM
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector
>   tryExecute INFO: Retrying request Nov 4, 2012 5:48:16 PM
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector
>   tryExecute INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when
>   processing request: Connection reset Nov 4, 2012 5:48:16 PM
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector
>   tryExecute INFO: Retrying request Nov 4, 2012 5:49:17 PM
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector
>   tryExecute INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when
>   processing request: Connection reset Nov 4, 2012 5:49:17 PM
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector
>   tryExecute INFO: Retrying request [DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking
>   file
>   /root/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.14/log4j-1.2.14.jar.lastUpdated
>   [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 4:03.016s [INFO] Finished at: Sun Nov 04 17:50:17
>   CET 2012 [INFO] Final Memory: 5M/15M [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project
>   jboss-ejb3-examples-ch04-firstejb: Could not resolve dependencies for
>   project
>   org.jboss.ejb3.examples:jboss-ejb3-examples-ch04-firstejb:jar:1.0.0-cr-1:
>   Could not transfer artifact log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14 from/to central
>   (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection reset -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal on project jboss-ejb3-examples-ch04-firstejb: Could not
>   resolve dependencies for project
>   org.jboss.ejb3.examples:jboss-ejb3-examples-ch04-firstejb:jar:1.0.0-cr-1:
>   Could not transfer artifact log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14 from/to central
>   (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection reset   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:258)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:201)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)   at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)   at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
>   Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException:
>   Could not resolve dependencies for project
>   org.jboss.ejb3.examples:jboss-ejb3-examples-ch04-firstejb:jar:1.0.0-cr-1:
>   Could not transfer artifact log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14 from/to central
>   (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection reset   at
>   org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:189)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:185)
>     ... 22 more Caused by:
>   org.sonatype.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Could
>   not transfer artifact log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14 from/to central
>   (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection reset   at
>   org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:375)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:183)
>     ... 23 more Caused by:
>   org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not
>   transfer artifact log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14 from/to central
>   (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection reset   at
>   org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:538)
>     at
>   org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
>     at
>   org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:358)
>     ... 24 more Caused by:
>   org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not
>   transfer artifact log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14 from/to central
>   (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection reset   at
>   org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:951)
>     at
>   org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:939)
>     at
>   org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:669)
>     at
>   org.sonatype.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:60)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) Caused by:
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Connection reset  at
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:799)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
>     at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
>     at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)  at
>   org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:601)
>     ... 4 more Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset    at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)   at
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:149)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:111)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:264)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:252)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:282)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:247)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:219)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:298)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:633)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:454)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.execute(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:674)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:793)
>     ... 8 more [ERROR]  [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more information about the
>   errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>   [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException

What is the problem? I think pom and other things are ok as it is example from book, so it should build.

Comment: `Could not transfer artifact log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)` - Looks like network issue, How many times you tried to build?

Comment: Was the *entire* stacktrace *absolutely* required???

Comment: i think network is ok, as other libs so far were downloaded ok.

Comment: The message show something different.

Comment: If you just tried it and it is giving you this exception, that may be because the repo.maven.apache.org is down it looks like. I have also been having problems. Accessing it gives a 503 error.

Answer (score 6):

Buried in there you'll see:

```
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2: Connection reset
```

You have a network problem. Maybe you're on wifi and getting interference... who knows.

Comment: i think network is ok, as other libs so far were downloaded ok.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it is IPv4 vs IPv6 incompatibility problem. you can try with mvn clean -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack. if it is,you can set to MVN_OPTIONS or disable IPv6 on your network adapter.
refer from:https://coderanch.com/t/588928/java-net-SocketException-caught-connecting

Answer (score 1):

I got same kind of problem - it was my anti virus who was blocked the port in behind. Disable anti-virus and or change firewall settings & it should work... :)

Answer (score 0):

Exception itself has the solution check the link in last line of the exception.

```
[ERROR] [ERROR] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Check it you may have one of those.

Comment: Problem was with maven version. However I had to install manually one lib (log4j).

Comment: @Pelsono consider adding that as an answer and clarifying the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - my builds were failing with "Connection Reset" messages, for all different dependencies, even though my internet connection seemed fine for other sites.

The problem went away when I upgraded Maven from version 3.0.4 to 3.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a **web proxy** entry/declaration to Maven [settings.xml](/home/<user>/.m2/settings.xml) as described in their [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html) resolved the ERROR messages if the current system is behind a web proxy.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, just sharing my solution. After checking that it wasn't a network issue. The error was that I had the wrong java version configured in the moment, I had 1.7 and this project was configured to work with 1.8. After changing it back, the code was built successfully and the references downloaded.

Hope it helps someone.